# RSS feed import all youtube channel videos

Tags: xml, youtube, rss, feed, subscription

I am using Inoreader for my YouTube subscriptions feed. But it shows videos only up to 5 years in past. I can't see videos, uploaded in 2014 and earlier. Is it possible somehow generate RSS feed, with all videos, uploaded by user, and than this import into Inoreader? 
I tried somehow create XML file with all videos, but no luck. I did manage to get URLs of all uploaded videos by user. If i would need than to get value of feed tags in XML file.

I also tried:
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=CHANNEL_ID

https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=USER_NAME

https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=PLAYLIST_UPLOADS

I don't have any more idea how to get old videos, any suggestion?

Comment: See point 1 I described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71130398/12511801) - AFAIK, RSS has no "pagination" that allows you retrieve *older/previous* data. So, you have to query the data and build the RSS programmatically. Good luck.