# Youtube RSS feed for live streams

Tags: youtube, rss

I want to get the RSS feed for all the videos of a channel, including live streams. I know about

> https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=

But this doesn't include "Past live streams" videos from the channel, only "Uploads" videos. How can you get live streams too in the feed?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need the info as RSS you could follow any of these options:

1. Use "[PlaylistItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems)" endpoint (or the endpoint available at https://yt.lemnoslife.com/) for get the items form the **`uploads`** playlist of the given channel - [see working example from YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UU0nggDVchmmO7ikV4NosYhg%22%7D) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031047/12511801) for more info about the "Uploads" playlist - check also the [response from yt.lemnoslife.com](https://yt.lemnoslife.com/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UU0nggDVchmmO7ikV4NosYhg)<sup>1</sup>, then, build an RSS feed programatically.
2. (*If you decide to generate the RSS feed with an RSS generator example: [FetchRSS](http://fetchrss.com/) - or any other tool*), then, you can copy and paste the URL of the "Uploads" playlist of the given channel - following your channel sample, the link is: **`https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UU0nggDVchmmO7ikV4NosYhg`** and let the RSS generator of your choice builds the RSS.
3. Use this endpoint - https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=<PLAYLIST_ID> - [credits to this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70933681/seeking-guidance#comment125473805_70951878) - in your use case, that would be: **`https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=UU0nggDVchmmO7ikV4NosYhg`** - notice the value of the playlist_id parameter - it's the "Uploads" of the channel "*UC0nggDVchmmO7ikV4NosYhg*".

---

<sup>1</sup> I found this website on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71012426/12511801).